# .htaccess: Transparently adding a name to the request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web2py

I've read [this](http://jdoe.asidev.com/2009/04/17/web2py-behind-apache-with-mod_wsgi-part-ii-mod_rewrite-rules/) tutorial about how to modify your .htaccess in order to server many web2py applications but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dispatch\.fcgi/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.moublemouble.com [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =moublemouble.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /moublemouble/$1 [PT,L]
```

All I get is a 500 Internal Error and .htaccess is not my strong point.
Any clues?

Comment: You may get more response on http://Severfault.com

Comment: I tried but the site seems broken

Comment: Did you take a look into the error log?

Comment: yeap, take a look at the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s either the illegal space in `[NC, OR]` or you are getting a recursion loop since the substitution `/moublemouble/…` is also matched by the pattern `^/(.*)`. So try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.moublemouble.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =moublemouble.com [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^moublemouble/
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /moublemouble/$1 [PT,L]
```

Or more compact:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?moublemouble\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^/moublemouble/ /moublemouble%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

Comment: The first one doesn't throw an error (the error was due to the space between [NC, OR]) but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: @Jon Romero: Try it without the `PT` flag and with the `R` flag for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It might be your RewriteCond causing the problem.

I haven't tried it, but you could try...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.moublemouble.com [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^moublemouble.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /moublemouble/$1 [L]
```

Comment: hmmm :( have you tried removing bits and by process of elimination, work out what's causing it to 500?

Comment: RewriteCond seems to be the error: 'RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters'